# Calculation over pandas groupby object with condition within groups

Tags: pandas, group-by, division

I have a `df` as follows:

```
    appid   month    tag totalvalue
0   1234    02-'22   B   50.00
1   1234    02-'22   BA  10.00
2   1234    01-'22   B   100.00
3   2345    03-'22   BA  25.00
4   2345    03-'22   B   100.00
5   2345    04-'22   BB  100.00
```

Output what I want is follows:

```
    appid   month    tag totalvalue  %tage
0   1234    02-'22   B   50.00       1.0
1   1234    02-'22   BA  10.00       0.2
2   1234    01-'22   B   100.00      1.0
3   2345    03-'22   BA  25.00       0.25
4   2345    03-'22   B   100.00      1.0  
5   2345    04-'22   BB  100.00      inf
```

I want to have group variables based on `appid` & `month`. Moreover want to check if there are `tag=B` is available in that `group` just divide other `tag`'s `totalvalue` with it. If not shows the `inf`

I have tried with `df.groupby(['appid', 'month'])['totalvalue']` but unable to replicate them with condition of `tag=B` as denominator over `groupby` object.

Comment: Your input is different from your output for month/tag/totalvalue in the last two rows

Comment: You're welcome. Have you tested my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use a `groupby.transform('first')` on the masked totalvalue, then use it a divider:

```
m = df['tag'].eq('B')

df['%tage'] = (df['totalvalue']
               .div(df['totalvalue'].where(m)
                    .groupby([df['appid'], df['month']])
                    .transform('first').fillna(0))
              )
```

output:

```
   appid   month tag  totalvalue  %tage
0   1234  02-'22   B        50.0   1.00
1   1234  02-'22  BA        10.0   0.20
2   1234  01-'22   B       100.0   1.00
3   2345  03-'22  BA        25.0   0.25
4   2345  03-'22   B       100.0   1.00
5   2345  04-'22  BB       100.0    inf
```